# Format all XML files in a directory and save them in a subdirectory

Tags: bash, find, xargs, xmllint

I'm trying to write a script that will look through a directory, find all the XML files, run them through `xmllint`, and save the formatted results to a file of the same name in a subdirectory called `formatted`. Here's the script I have so far:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.xml" | xargs -I '{}' xmllint --format '{}' > formatted/'{}'
```

This works, to an extent. The subdirectory ends up with one file, named `"{}"`, which is just the results of the final file that was processed through `xmllint`. How can I get the files to write properly to the subdirectory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The file named `{}` that you see should probably contain *all* of the formatted files together. The reason for this is that the redirection that you are using is not actually a part of the command that `xargs` sees. The redirection is interpreted by the shell, so what it does is run

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.xml" | xargs -I '{}' xmllint --format '{}'
```

and save the output to the file named `formatted/{}`.

Try using the `--output` option of `xmllint` instead of the redirection:

```
... | xargs -I '{}' xmllint --format '{}' --output formatted/'{}'
```

You can also avoid calling `xargs` by using the `-exec` option of `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.xml" -exec xmllint --format '{}' --output formatted/'{}' \;
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the `--output` option for xmllint. I tested both solutions (with `xargs` and with `-exec`) and they both work perfectly. Interestingly, the `find` man page mentions that "only one instance of `'{}'` is allowed within the command" when you use `-exec`, which is why I originally had opted for `xargs`, but it worked just fine.

Comment: @Ben In my version of the man page, the phrase is there for the `-exec command {} +` syntax, but here the `-exec command ;` syntax is used, which is described several lines above in the man page.