# Add correct indentation to XML string

Tags: xml, go

We've got a legacy system with XML where the XML is not pretty (i.e. entire file has no line breaks).

Is there a built in/native way to achieve pretty printing of XML in go? If not how does one go about achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`xml.MarshalIndent`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#MarshalIndent), for example :

```
package main

type xmldoc struct { ........ fields ...... }

func main() {
    var doc xmlDoc
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xml-data), &doc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    out, err := xml.MarshalIndent(doc, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

or from the command line you can always use `xmlint` :

```
$ xmllint --format --recover file.xml > formatted.xml
```

or do it in bulk check [Format all XML files in a directory and save them in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577191/format-all-xml-files-in-a-directory-and-save-them-in-a-subdirectory)

Comment: What fields go in xmldoc? Are you saying we need to create an xmldoc struct for each XML file type that we have? that could be thousands (literally)

Comment: Well yes, that's how xml works in go, or you can write your own parser or just use xmllint.